# Repository is not autowired, it is null

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, nullpointerexception, autowired

I have upgraded the spring boot version to 2.7.8. After that when I try to build my project I'm getting  errors in unit tests. Repository is not getting autowired. It is null. because of that I'm getting below issue.

```java
public class CRUDAppServiceTest extends BaseTest {


    @Autowired
    private LocationRepository locationRepository;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        this.externalItemId = "abc";
        this.externalLocationId = "123";
        this.itemId = "xyz";
        final String locationId = "321";

        this.locationCreate(this.externalLocationId, locationId);
    }

    private void locationCreate(final String extPosLocationId, final String locationId) {
        final Map<String, String> attributes= new HashMap<>();
        attributes.put(ConnectorConstants.USE_86ING, "true");

        final MenuImportConfig menuImportConfig = new MenuImportConfig();
        menuImportConfig.setAttributes(attributes);

        final Location location = new Location();
        location.setExtPosLocationId(extPosLocationId);
        location.setLocationId(locationId);
        location.setMenuImportConfig(menuImportConfig);

        this.locationRepository.save(location);
    }

    @Test
    public void successTest() throws Exception {
        final PatchRequestDTO patchRequest = new PatchRequestDTO();
        patchRequest.setOp(Operation.TEST); // does not matter in this case
        patchRequest.setPath("stock");
        patchRequest.setValue("IN_STOCK");

        final List<PatchRequestDTO> patchRequests = Arrays.asList(patchRequest);

        this.mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.patch("/item/" + this.itemId)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(GSON.toJson(patchRequests))).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    }

}
```

Getting `successTestFAILED java.lang.NullPointerException`

Please explain what I have done wrong and how to correct it?
Also, I have used below code snippet in BaseTest class.

```java
@AutoConfigureDataMongo
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
// empty in-memory MongoDB between each test
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {
    MyService.class
}, properties = {
    "order.notification.email.type=HTML",
    "aws.paramstore.enabled=false",
    "spring.main.banner-mode=off",
    "spring.mongodb.embedded.version=4.4.0"
})
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Comment: So you don't use any configuration and expect things to auto magically work? Next to that you are mixing JUnit4 and JUnit5 (`Before` is from Junit4, you should have `@BeforeEach`). YOur `@SpringBootTest` should not have any `classes` but should detect the configuration itself. The `@ExtendWIth` isn't needed nor is the `@WebAppConfiguration`. Most important from this list, don't mix junit4/junit5 and remove the `classes` from `@SpringBootTest`.

Comment: Use `@DataJpa` for the repository tests